# insert binary data into BLOB using python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert a binary number to a blob field in mysql using python.

I uses python 2.7 and pymysql for connection

```
connection = db.cursor()

query = """ INSERT INTO mytable (bin) VALUES (%s)"""

connection.execute(query,(binarynumber))
```

And i am getting the error

```
KeyError: <type 'bytearray'>
```

I can easily insert integer numbers in the blob field, but obviously my binarynumber has a wrong format somehow. Anyone knows what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the whole traceback of the exception?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm only allowed to write generic code to stackoverflow :(

Comment: Can you reproduce the error using generic code so you can post that whole traceback?